# Search text field shifts down to new line in Nav block

Tags: search, theming

I enable the search module "core module" and then I place the search block in the Navigation region of my Bootstrap subtheme. In Firefox it renders it correctly. placing it just to the left and in-line with the "My Account" and "Log out" links - in the upper right corner of my site. When I view it in IE or Chrome the search text field and search button fall below those links and increasing the height of the Nav section of the site. I would like it to be in-line as it is in FF either before or after the "My Account" and "Log out" links. I have not tweaked any CSS. Can someone please be kind enough to assist me. I am still a noob at Drupal and Bootstrap so forgive me if this is this is an easy fix but not apparent to me. You're assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know If further info is needed in order to troubleshoot.

Kind Regards,
Evan

[image]